How to solve error message from interpolating in R? : ('as.is' should be specified by the caller; using TRUE)
I get this error message when I try to take away a part of the intepolation with data (etp_data) I'm no longer using:
"Warning messages:
1: In type.convert.default(x) :
'as.is' should be specified by the caller; using TRUE"
Can someone please help me with what is wrong? Thank you!!!!
This is the old code that is working:

interp_AR6_data <- (ss0 %>% interp.all(id.cols=5) %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>%   # Structured as a df 
    melt(id = c(1:5), variable.name='Year') %>%

    dcast(`Model` + `Scenario` + `Year` ~ `Variable`, value.var='value') %>%    
    
   mutate(`Model-Scenario`=paste(`Model`, `Scenario`, sep='-'),  
           Year = as.numeric(as.character(Year))
    ) %>%
        select(c(ncol(.), 1:(ncol(.)-1)))
    )


if(use_etp) {
  flog.debug('Pulling ETP data')
  interp_etp_data <- (get.ETP.data()
                      %>% interp.all(id.cols=1)
                      %>% melt(id.vars='Variable', variable.name = 'Year')
                      %>% dcast(Year ~ Variable)
                      %>% mutate(
                        `Model-Scenario`='ETP-2DS',
                        `Model`='ETP',
                        `Scenario`='2DS',
                        Year = as.numeric(as.character(Year))
                      )
                      %>% select(c((ncol(.)-2):ncol(.), 1:(ncol(.)-2)))
                      %>% rename(Cement = 'Cement ')
                      %>% arrange(Year))
  interp_data <- (interp_AR6_data
                  %>% merge(interp_etp_data[, -c(1:3)], by='Year'))
  
} else {
  interp_data <- (interp_AR6_data)
}

and this is the new code I am trying with:

interp_AR6_data <- (ss0 %>% interp.all(id.cols=5) %>%
                      as.data.frame() %>%   # Structured as a df
           
                      melt(id = c(1:5), variable.name='Year') %>%
                      
                      dcast(`Model` + `Scenario` + `Year` ~ `Variable`, value.var='value') %>%
                      mutate(
                        
                        `Model-Scenario`=paste(`Model`, `Scenario`, sep='-'),  
                        Year = as.numeric(as.character(Year)),
                      ) %>%
                      select(c(ncol(.), 1:(ncol(.)-1))) 
                    )




Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read this link as a start. You need to provide the code in a way that we just copy paste it and we will be able to run it on our own. Add a minimal dataset using head() and dput()
